# How to cut a VOB file with FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, vob

How do I cut a decrypted VOB file with FFmpeg?

For example, to keep the first 5 minutes of a VOB file?

Comment: I'm trying to cut a VOB file. It is decrypted.

Comment: 'Cut' meaning trim and *remove* the first 5 minutes, or cut meaning trim and *keep* the first five minutes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-t 00:05:00` in your `ffmpeg` command. This limits the output to the first 5 minutes.

```
ffmpeg -i input.VOB -t 00:05:00 [other options like video and audio codec] < output file >
```

Comment: Does that work with *encrypted* VOBs?

Comment: Well encrypted VOBs are encrypted for a reason, so I guess not. Give it a try.

Comment: I ask because the OP specified encrypted in comments, and if this does work on encrypted VOBs it's worth making that explicit :)

Comment: @bertieb I never said that the VOBs are encrypted.